# How do you work out possible Permutation of multiple variables

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I was looking recently into how to generate unique compilations of images from sets. I was looking into NFTs and as a developer was just curious how they work.

I then was trying to figure out how many possible permutations could be made from images without repetition but (sorry if I sound noobie here) it seems a little complicated.

For example, the possible permutations of 3 would be 6.

```
1,2,3
2,1,3
3,1,2
1,3,2
2,3,1
3,2,1
```

However, with the way NFTs work you have different sets. So for example:

If the NFT had 3 attributes and 3 different types

Eyes  x3

Mouth x3

Legs x3

is that correct? would the answer be **18**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function that does this, called the "factorial" function. For example, let's consider the number of ways to arrange 5 distinct objects. There are 5 options for the first object, and 4 options for the second object, 3 for the third, 2 for the fourth and 1 for the last one. So the total number of arrangements is $5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 120$. We denote $n\cdot (n-1)\cdot ...\cdot 2\cdot 1$ as $n!$, read "$n$ *factorial*".

If your NFT had 3 attributes, and each attribute has $3!$ possible arrangements, then there are $(3!) \cdot (3!) \cdot (3!) = (3!)^3 = 6^3 = 216$ possible NFTs.

Comment: Thank you for a quick and easy to understand reply.